# PHP / MYSQL Insert Array Foreach Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

This one has me pretty rattled so I thank you in advance for your assistance.  There seem to be a number of walkthroughs on this topic but it seems I may be skinning this cat a bit different. . . .

I have a purchase order form that I'm using javascript to dynamically add rows to a table and capture data for multiple line items. I'm then collecting data for each column in an array.  For example I have "Cust_PN", "Qty", "Price" as columns and arrays for each. . . Cust_PN[0] Cust_PN[1] and Cust_PN[2] for line items 1-3 respectively.  I then have Qty[0], Qty[1], and Qty[2] and so on.

I can get this to echo properly without issue. However, when I go to post I am only posting the array data from the last entry *[3] per my example above.

I currently have the following code/query. . . again any help would be much appreciated.

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO SO_Items (Timestamp,SO_Num,SO_Rev,SO_Line_Item,Cust_PN,Cust_PN_Rev,My_PN,My_PN_Rev,Description,
  Qty,Sale_Price,UOM,Program,Required_Date) 
  SELECT NOW(),'$SO_Num','$SO_Rev','$SO_Line_Item[$a]','$Cust_PN[$a]','$Cust_PN_Rev[$a]','$My_PN[$a]','$My_PN_Rev[$a]','$Description[$a]','$Qty[$a]','$Sale_Price[$a]','$UOM[$a]','$Program[$a]','$Required_Date[$a]'" or die ('Error posting data');



foreach($Cust_PN as $a => $b) {
  mysql_query($query1);
  }
```

I'm quite certain there are a number of issues in the above. . . thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you start here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/

Comment: What is the actual error? "I can get this to echo properly...": where is that mentioned `echo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is, declaring `$query` outside the loop.
It makes it a constant, and that too, takes values `$a` and `$b` which are that time, undefined, so results in invalid syntax for SQL.

```
foreach($Cust_PN as $a => $b) {
   $query1 = "INSERT INTO SO_Items (Timestamp, SO_Num, SO_Rev, SO_Line_Item, Cust_PN, Cust_PN_Rev, My_PN, My_PN_Rev, Description, Qty, Sale_Price, UOM, Program, Required_Date) VALUES (NOW(), '$SO_Num', '$SO_Rev', '$SO_Line_Item[$a]', '$Cust_PN[$a]', '$Cust_PN_Rev[$a]', '$My_PN[$a]', '$My_PN_Rev[$a]', '$Description[$a]', '$Qty[$a]', '$Sale_Price[$a]', '$UOM[$a]', '$Program[$a]', '$Required_Date[$a]');";

   $q = mysql_query($query1) or die ('Error posting data');

 }
```

Try that.
Fixed your SQL query too. Correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

You had put `SELECT` in place of `VALUES`

Let me know if it works, and otherwise please tell what error it ives exactly.

Comment: Sweet! Putting the query inside the loop did the trick. Can't believe it was that straight forward!  I left the sql syntax unchanged. . . I prefer that insert method as outlined at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html  Seems that if my table ever changes I won't have broken forms out of the gate.   THANK YOU!

Comment: Oh, ok, interesting. Glad you got it working then. (By the way, Could you accept the answer please?)

Answer (score 2):

foreach must be before the $query1 :

```
foreach($Cust_PN as $a => $b) {

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO SO_Items (Timestamp,SO_Num,SO_Rev,SO_Line_Item,Cust_PN,Cust_PN_Rev,My_PN,My_PN_Rev,Description,
    Qty,Sale_Price,UOM,Program,Required_Date) 
    VALUES(NOW(),'$SO_Num','$SO_Rev','$SO_Line_Item[$a]','$Cust_PN[$a]','$Cust_PN_Rev[$a]','$My_PN[$a]','$My_PN_Rev[$a]','$Description[$a]','$Qty[$a]','$Sale_Price[$a]','$UOM[$a]','$Program[$a]','$Required_Date[$a]')" or die ('Error posting data');

    mysql_query($query1);

  }
```

Comment: SQL query is still erratic. Fixed in my answer.